# Handling Graphql Mutation With Python Requests

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql

I'm trying to work with waveapps API. And it seems I'm not getting the mutation operation right.

I want to create a [Transaction via WaveApps API](https://developer.waveapps.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019968212-API-Reference#moneytransactioncreateinput).  Below is my code:

```
query = """ mutation ($input: MoneyTransactionCreateInput!) {moneyTransactionCreate(input: $input) {moneyTransaction {id externalId date description anchor{accountId amount direction} lineItems[{accountId amount balance}]}}}"""

moneyTransaction = {'businessId':'5ODAtNzQ3OS00ZGQ4LTg5NWYtMzU4ZWNiNDNmMTI2', 
'externalId':'21', 'date':'2020-05-16', 'description':'my money', 'anchor':{'accountId':'1', 
'amount':'15.00', 'direction':'DEPOSIT'},
'lineItems':[{'accountId':'1', 'amount':'15.00', 'balance':'CREDIT'}]}

variables = {'input': moneyTransaction}

rex = requests.post(wave_url, json={'query':query, 'variables':variables}, headers=after_headers)
```

I got this error:

```
'{"errors":[{"extensions":{"id":"e6b88a8d-a5f8-4331-80db-191dbb319690","code":"GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED"},"message":"Syntax Error: Expected Name, found [","locations":[{"line":1,"column":183}]}]}\n'
```

I'm missing something but can't figure out the issue. I'm new to Graphql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has extraneous square brackets inside it. Square brackets are only used when specifying a List type -- there's never a need to use them inside a selection set.

```
mutation ($input: MoneyTransactionCreateInput!) {
  moneyTransactionCreate(input: $input) {
    moneyTransaction {
      id
      externalId
      date
      description
      anchor {
        accountId
        amount
        direction
      }
      lineItems {
        accountId
        amount
        balance
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked too.

```
mutation ($inputMoneyTransactionCreate: MoneyTransactionCreateInput!) {
  moneyTransactionCreate(input: $inputMoneyTransactionCreate) {
    didSucceed
    inputErrors {
      code
      message
      path
    }
  }
}
```

And variable was changed to:

```
variables = {'inputMoneyTransactionCreate': moneyTransaction}
```